# Ajax stopped working suddenly on entire webstie

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and for some reason, all the AJAX features stopped working. Auto plugin and WordPress update are turned off and I haven't made any changes. I even uploaded a backup of all theme files and still the same problem. There are no JS errors and responses are coming in as ok (no 500 errors). I have no ideas on where to even start looking.  Any suggestion would be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Somehow a `<p>nbsp</p>` got saved at the top of one of my php files. Not easy to find since it doesn't cause any errors.